# How to fix error caused by @data in visual studio code 2019 in ASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

I am a little new to ASM. I am trying to find the smallest value in an DWORD array. I am getting an error A2006: undefined symbol: DGROUP on line 11 in my code. I believe the @data is causing my error. How should I modify my code to solve this problem??? I am using 32-bit visual studio code 2019. Thanks for your time!

```
.model small
.stack
.data
          msg1 db 0dh,0ah, 'smallest element is:$'
          array db 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, -2, -5, 8, 6
          smallest db ?
.code

main proc
          mov ax,@data
          mov ds,ax
          lea di,array

          mov cx,9 ; 5 times count
          mov al,[di] ; memory location send ‘di’ registerar data ‘al’
          mov smallest,al

          step:  ;level
                   inc di
                   mov bl,[di]

                   cmp smallest,bl
                   jle l1  ;jge= jump gratherthan equal ,

                   mov smallest,bl
          l1:
                   loop step
                   add smallest,30h ; integer to character (add30 for asii value)

                   lea dx,msg1

                   mov ah,09h
                   int 21h

                   mov dl,smallest
                   mov ah,02h
                   int 21h
         
          mov ah,4ch
          int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: `.data` is a section name. Use appropriate variables names, eg `msg1`, `array`, `smallest`

Comment: I don't think you are using the correct `masm` version. You need the 16 bit one as this is 16 bit DOS code.